# Где находится папка Отправленные в ВКонтакте?

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Я загружаю документ в ВКонтакте, а как отправить его на стену? `wall.post` нельзя вызвать с ключом доступа пользователя. Какие есть альтернативы?

В документации говорится про `docs.getWallUploadServer`:

> Возвращает адрес сервера для загрузки документов в папку **отправленные**, для последующей отправки документа на стену или личным сообщением.

Где эта папка и как ей пользоваться?

**UPD**

Я хочу отправить документ и текст на стену группы через Java веб-приложение. Для этого загружаю документ в группу через `docs.getWallUploadServer` и сохраняю через `docs.save`. Из полученных данных я пытался сделать сделать пост на стену группы, но получил ответ:

> User authorization failed: method is unavailable with group auth.

Код

```
final String title = params.get("title");

URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder();
uriBuilder.setScheme("https").setHost("api.vk.com").setPath("/method/docs.getWallUploadServer")
    .setParameter("access_token", Social.VK_SECRET)
    .setParameter("group_id", Social.VK_GROUP_ID);

HttpResponse response = HttpConnectionAgent.connectResponseGet(uriBuilder);
StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();

if (null != status && 200 == status.getStatusCode()) {
  try {
    JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(response.getEntity().getContent());

    JsonObject responseObject = jsonReader.readObject();
    System.out.println(responseObject);
    JsonObject resp = responseObject.getJsonObject("response");
    String uploadUrl = resp.getString("upload_url");
    uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(uploadUrl);//.setParameter("access_token", Social.VK_SECRET);
    System.out.println(uriBuilder);
    HttpResponse uploadResponse = HttpConnectionAgent.connectResponsePost(uriBuilder, getFileName(params), data.toByteArray());
    status = uploadResponse.getStatusLine();
    if (null != status && 200 == status.getStatusCode()) {
      jsonReader = Json.createReader(uploadResponse.getEntity().getContent());

      responseObject = jsonReader.readObject();
      logger.info(responseObject);

      final String file = responseObject.getString("file", null);

      if (null == file) {
        System.out.println("File isn't uploaded");
        return null;
      }
      uriBuilder = new URIBuilder();
      uriBuilder.setScheme("https").setHost("api.vk.com").setPath("/method/docs.save");
      uriBuilder.setParameter("file", file);
      uriBuilder.setParameter("title", title);
      uriBuilder.setParameter("tags", params.get("tags"));
      uriBuilder.setParameter("access_token", Social.VK_SECRET);
      HttpResponse saveResponse = HttpConnectionAgent.connectResponseGet(uriBuilder);
      jsonReader = Json.createReader(saveResponse.getEntity().getContent());
      responseObject = jsonReader.readObject();
      logger.info(responseObject);

      final JsonObject savedDoc = (JsonObject) ((JsonArray) responseObject.get("response")).get(0);
      String vkToken = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(Config.VK_ACCESS_TOKEN_PATH)).get(0);
      uriBuilder = new URIBuilder();
      String ownerId = String.valueOf(savedDoc.get("owner_id"));
      uriBuilder.setScheme("https").setHost("api.vk.com").setPath("/method/wall.post");
      uriBuilder.setParameter("owner_id", ownerId);
      uriBuilder.setParameter("from_group", "1");
      uriBuilder.setParameter("message", title);
      List<String> attachments = new ArrayList<>();
      String did = savedDoc.get("did").toString();
      attachments.add("doc" + ownerId + "_" + did);
      attachments.add(params.get("link"));
      uriBuilder.setParameter("attachments", attachments.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
      uriBuilder.setParameter("access_token", vkToken);
      HttpResponse postResponse = HttpConnectionAgent.connectResponseGet(uriBuilder);
      jsonReader = Json.createReader(postResponse.getEntity().getContent());
      responseObject = jsonReader.readObject();
      logger.info(responseObject);
    }
  } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Оформите решение как ответ на собственный вопрос. В текущем виде после редактирования у вас вполне полноценный ответ и полноценный вопрос.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Спасибо, я отмечу позже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решил путем использования токена полученного в результате перехода по этому адресу https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=12345&scope=groups,wall,offline&redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&display=page&v=5.21&response_type=token